# Highstock not displaying year on tooltip

Tags: highcharts

Instead of showing the year in the tooltip, my highstock graph is showing time. It seems that my options are set the same as the demo, does anyone know why this may be happening?

This is my tooltip: 
[image]

This is what I want it to look like: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your data has different granularity than official demo. You can control what is displayed in tooltip using [`tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats)

I suggest to set it this way:

```
dataTimeLabelFormats: {
  millisecond:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L",
  second:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S",
  minute:"%A, %b %e, %Y",
  hour:"%A, %b %e, %Y",
  day:"%A, %b %e, %Y",
  week:"Week from %A, %b %e, %Y",
  month:"%B %Y",
  year:"%Y"
}
```